# Проблемы с редактированием текста на сайте

Tags: поддержка, статус-проверка

Пытаюсь редактировать текст в своем ответе - выделить в тексте курсивом и жирным некоторые места, не получается. Функции исчезают. Скриншот представить не могу, даже здесь отсутсвует возможность добавить фото с компьютера. В чем проблема? Может, кто-нибудь знает?

При правке редактор исчезает, как показано на скриншоте.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/znq2M.png

Comment: Добрый день! Пожалуйста, подскажите, используете ли вы какое–либо расширение для сайта (на снимке виднеется какая–то зеленая кнопка)? Проявляется ли проблема в другом обозревателе? Будет ли проблема повторятся, если вы откажитесь от увеличения?

Comment: Нет, я ничего не использую. Зеленая кнопка - это Grammarly for Firefox. К этому сайту не имеет отношения.

Comment: Подскажите, а вот без этого расширения будет ли появляться ошибка?

Comment: Нет, я удалял, проблма остается.

Comment: С огромной вероятностью, проблема именно на клиенте (то есть в вашем обозревателе). Описываемое вами поведение крайне похоже на то, когда расширения входят в конфликт между собой или страничкой. Пожалуйста, подскажите, возможно вы все–таки используете/использовали какие–либо расширения для редактора Markdown? Был бы признателен за информацию о наличие ошибок в консоли (в меню открывающемуся по нажатию на правую кнопку мыши выбрать «инспектор», справа внизу цифра рядом с красной иконкой).

Comment: Николай, спасибо, что откликнулись. Я нажала на эту красную кнопку. В меню консуль Защита (там же красная кнопка). Но ничего не открывается.

Comment: Вот сейчас тоже пробую, проблема осталась. Я постараюсь открыть новый профиль, чтобы узнать, проблема связана с компьютером или со страницой.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пожалуйста, очистите кеш браузера и попробуйте снова. Если ошибка повторится, приложите скриншот (воспользуйтесь интернет-хостингом фото, например https://imgur.com/upload, и прикрепите ссылку) и подробно опишите, что вы делали.

В любом случае вы можете использовать функции редактора Markdown с помощью специальных символов: * с обеих сторон слова для *курсива*, ** — для **жирного шрифта** и
т. д. Подробнее: https://rus.meta.stackexchange.com/editing-help.

Comment: Спасибо! С другого компьютера все получилось!Видимо, проблема была в моем компьютере. Я имею в виду редакцию. А как быть, если не могу опубликовать вопрос?

Comment: @Наталья если система пишет, что вопрос не отвечает стандартам качества, то речь идет об этих параметрах: тело вопроса должно содержать не менее 30 символов, заголовок — не менее 15. Скажите, были ли они соблюдены?

Comment: @ Aer,проблема повторилась, причем я компьютер чистила. Скриншот в выложить в этом ответе, дополнив его, или заново задать вопрос?

Comment: @Наталья вы можете обновить этот вопрос или просто прикрепить ссылку к комментарию.

Comment: А как добавить скриншот, если в поле для вопроса нет такой функции?

Comment: @Наталья я описал один из возможных вариантов в своем ответе: прикрепите ссылку на скриншот.

Comment: Спасибо, сделала, как вы сказали - прикрепила скриншот.

Comment: @Наталья хорошо. Я передам ваш вопрос специалистам. Как будет дан ответ, напишу.

Comment: Спасибо большое!